# Can I recreate this polar coordinate spider chart in plotly?

Tags: r, plotly

I'm having a bit of difficulty figuring out how to recreate the following graphic of a spider (or radar) chart, using plotly. Actually, I can't even recreate it in the most recent versions of ggplot2 because there have been breaking changes since 1.0.1.

Here's an example graphic:

[image]

Here's the original function that built it:

http://pcwww.liv.ac.uk/~william/Geodemographic%20Classifiability/func%20CreateRadialPlot.r

Here's an example of how the original function worked:

http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/5795_e6e6411731bb4f1b9cc7eb49499c2082.html

Here's some not so dummy data:

```
d <- structure(list(Year = rep(c("2015","2016"),each=24),
                    Response = structure(rep(1L:24L,2), 
                                         .Label = c("Trustworthy", "Supportive", "Leading",
                                                    "Strong", "Dependable", "Consultative",
                                                    "Knowledgeable", "Sensible", 
                                                    "Intelligent", "Consistent", "Stable", 
                                                    "Innovative", "Aggressive", 
                                                    "Conservative", "Visionary", 
                                                    "Arrogant", "Professional", 
                                                    "Responsive", "Confident", "Accessible", 
                                                    "Timely", "Focused", "Niche", "None"),
                                         class = "factor"), 
                    Proportion = c(0.54, 0.48, 0.33, 0.35, 0.47, 0.3, 0.43, 0.29, 0.36,
                                   0.38, 0.45, 0.32, 0.27, 0.22, 0.26,0.95, 0.57, 0.42, 
                                   0.38, 0.5, 0.31, 0.31, 0.12, 0.88, 0.55, 0.55, 0.31,
                                   0.4, 0.5, 0.34, 0.53, 0.3, 0.41, 0.41, 0.46, 0.34, 
                                   0.22, 0.17, 0.28, 0.94, 0.62, 0.46, 0.41, 0.53, 0.34, 
                                   0.36, 0.1, 0.84), n = rep(c(240L,258L),each=24)),
               .Names = c("Year", "Response", "Proportion", "n"), 
               row.names = c(NA, -48L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Here's my attempt (not very good)

```
plot_ly(d, r = Proportion, t = Response, x = Response, 
        color = factor(Year), mode = "markers") %>%
layout(margin = list(l=50,r=0,b=0,t=0,pad = 4), showlegend = TRUE)
```

Any thoughts on how I might be able to recreate this using plotly?

Comment: I'm curious to learn why the recent `ggplot2` version broke your existing code. Or, to put it the other way around, why are you asking for a `plotly` solution and not for a fix of your existing `ggplot2` code?

Comment: @UweBlock It's based on code I don't understand very well, that will likely take a significant amount of time to debug and fix. My first couple of tries with plotly gave me a very close solution. So I figured someone with more experience would see the plot and perhaps know how to do it.

I've included the function and an example of how it's used in an update to the question above. You're welcome to take a stab at fixing the ggplot code.

Comment: have you tried to replace mode="markers" with mode="lines"?

Comment: There is a simple way to convert `ggplot2` plots into `plotly` using `ggplotly(yourplot)` https://plot.ly/ggplot2/getting-started/ . However, I couldn't make it work with this sort of plot. Here is a static `ggplot2` plot of your data `ggplot(d, aes(y = Proportion, x = Response, group = factor(Year), colour = factor(Year))) + coord_polar() + geom_point() + geom_path()`

Comment: @MLavoie yes, but there is a problem with how it lines up, and I don't know how to put the "xaxis" labels for each of the attributes around the circle.

Comment: @RafaelPereira same problem here. Hence the question!

Comment: First remove `face="bold"` from the function(four instances), or replace it with `fontface="bold"`, then `dat <- reshape2::dcast(data=d, Year ~ Response, value.var="Proportion")`. You then need to rename the first column as `group`, so `names(dat)[1] <- "group"`, then `ggplotly(CreateRadialPlot(dat, grid.max=1))`. But, the plotly figure does not have the labels, and you will need to tweak other arguments to line up some stuffs.

Comment: So I thought I might be able to mock up a slightly more detailed polar chart, but I found some issues. First, setting the details on the `angularaxis` in layout is a nightmare, `nticks` will get you close to what you want, but won't let you get all of the parameters, (I think I got the closest with 33, but at 34 it drops back down to a small number of ticks). The `hoverinfo` gives you exactly what you want, but weirdly, you can't use the text parameter the same way as with a cartesian plot.  From everything I can tell, polar is just not a well-supported format in plotly.

Comment: @user20650 you got that to work in ggplot2 v2+ ?

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen; yes, v2.1.0 - after changing the four `face` arguments in the `geom_text` calls

Comment: @user20650 Did it work with plotly?

Comment: Hi @BrandonBertelsen; ggplotly converted the figure but did not have the labels around the edges - hence just leaving it as a comment. The above code prepares your data, and corrects the ggplot code (of CreateRadialPlot)  but needs work on the plotly, which hopefully someone else can further (as I don't use it at all). Have you managed to get the static CreateRadialPlot working, by removing (or replacing) the `face="bold"` arguments?

Comment: Also when I used ggplotly to convert the example code from the link in your question, iy also omitted the labels, so I wonder if there is an issue with geom_text calls getting rendered.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The options available with polar plots are still limited.  There is not, so far as I can tell, any way to add text to a polar plot for the category labels around the circumference. Neither text scatter points, nor annotations nor tick labels (except at the four quarter points) are compatible with polar coordinates in plotly at the moment.

So, we need to get a little creative.

One type of polar coordinate system that does work nicely is a projected map of a sperical earth using an azimuthal projection.  Here is a demonstration of how you might adapt that to this problem.

First, convert the values to plot into latitude and longitudes centred on the South pole:

```
scale <- 10   # multiply latitudes by a factor of 10 to scale plot to good size in initial view
d$lat <- scale*d$Proportion - 90
d$long <- (as.numeric(d$Response)-1) * 360/24
```

Plot using an azimuthal equidistant projection

```
p <- plot_ly(d[c(1:24,1,25:48,25),], lat=lat, lon=long, color = factor(Year), colors=c('#F8756B','#00BDC2'),
             type = 'scattergeo', mode = 'lines+markers', showlegend=T) %>%
layout(geo = list(scope='world', showland=F, showcoastlines=F, showframe=F,
             projection = list(type = 'azimuthal equidistant', rotation=list(lat=-90), scale=5)), 
             legend=list(x=0.7,y=0.85))
```

Put some labels on

```
p %<>% add_trace(type="scattergeo",  mode = "text", lat=rep(scale*1.1-90,24), lon=long, 
                 text=Response, showlegend=F, textfont=list(size=10)) %>%
       add_trace(type="scattergeo",  mode = "text", showlegend=F, textfont=list(size=12),
                 lat=seq(-90, -90+scale,length.out = 5), lon=rep(0,5), 
                 text=c("","25%","50%","75%","100%"))
```

Finally, add grid lines

```
l1 <- list(width = 0.5, color = rgb(.5,.5,.5), dash = "3px")
l2 <- list(width = 0.5, color = rgb(.5,.5,.5))
for (i in c(0.1, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1)) 
    p <- add_trace(lat=rep(-90, 100)-scale*i, lon=seq(0,360, length.out=100), type='scattergeo', mode='lines', line=l1, showlegend=F, evaluate=T)
for (i in 1:24) 
    p <- add_trace(p,lat=c(-90+scale*0.1,-90+scale), lon=rep(i*360/24,2), type='scattergeo', mode='lines', line=l2, showlegend=F, evaluate=T)
```

[image]

## Update for plotly version 4.x

Breaking changes in the updates to plotly mean that the original version no longer works without a few modifications to bring it up to date.  here is an updated version:

```
library(data.table)
gridlines1 = data.table(lat = -90 + scale*(c(0.1, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1)))
gridlines1 = gridlines1[, .(long = c(seq(0,360, length.out=100), NA)), by = lat]
gridlines1[is.na(long), lat := NA]

gridlines2 = data.table(long = seq(0,360, length.out=25)[-1])
gridlines2 = gridlines2[, .(lat = c(NA, -90, -90+scale, NA)), by = long]
gridlines2[is.na(lat), long := NA]

text.labels = data.table(
  lat=seq(-90, -90+scale,length.out = 5),
  long = 0,
  text=c("","25%","50%","75%","100%"))

p = plot_ly() %>%
add_trace(type="scattergeo", data = d[c(1:24, 1, 25:48, 25),], 
      lat=~lat, lon=~long, 
      color = factor(d[c(1:24, 1, 25:48, 25),]$Year), 
      mode = 'lines+markers')%>%
layout(geo = list(scope='world', showland=F, showcoastlines=F, showframe=F,
    projection = list(type = 'azimuthal equidistant', rotation=list(lat=-90), scale=5)), 
    legend = list(x=0.7, y=0.85)) %>%
add_trace(data = gridlines1, lat=~lat, lon=~long, 
    type='scattergeo', mode='lines', line=l1, 
    showlegend=F, inherit = F)  %>%
add_trace(data = gridlines2, lat=~lat, lon=~long,
    type='scattergeo', mode='lines', line=l2, showlegend=F) %>%
add_trace(data = text.labels, lat=~lat, lon=~long, 
  type="scattergeo", mode = "text", text=~text, textfont = list(size = 12),
    showlegend=F, inherit=F) %>%
add_trace(data = d, lat=-90+scale*1.2, lon=~long, 
    type="scattergeo", mode = "text", text=~Response, textfont = list(size = 10),
    showlegend=F, inherit=F) 

p
```

Comment: This is an excellent approach. The only thing that's missing is the legend, that's a critical piece of the presentation.

Comment: The result of the static graphic is great. But you can't zoom or move the graph around because it takes the shape of map projection (like looking at a planet)

Comment: zooming should work, but panning will rotate the planet.  It wasn't really specified in the question that this would be a requirement - and since the ggplot version you are trying to replicate doesn't zoom and pan, it certainly wasn't clear that these functions were what you  were after.

Comment: It's very close to what I want. I like the approach, but yes, of course I want to use plotly because of it's interactive elements. Although I've only chosen two groups here, the actual usage case is to compare an industry or something of that nature.

Comment: Ok, it's not hard to adapt this approach to these requirements. Just need to project the points onto a small area near the pole, rather onto the whole globe, to avoid any spherical (non-Cartesian) distortions. I've updated to show how.

Comment: I get multiple errors saying that `lat`, `lon` and `text` should be either 48 or 1 long. I suppose the plotly update did ruin your code

Comment: thanks @5th - see updates for plotly 4.x I just added

Answer (score 6):

I've made some progress with this, by faking it. Polar coords, seem to just hate me:

data:

```
df <- d <- structure(list(Year = c("2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", 
"2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", 
"2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", 
"2015", "2015", "2015", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", 
"2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", 
"2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", 
"2016", "2016", "2016"), Response = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 
22L, 23L, 24L), .Label = c("Trustworthy", "Supportive", "Leading", 
"Strong", "Dependable", "Consultative", "Knowledgeable", "Sensible", 
"Intelligent", "Consistent", "Stable", "Innovative", "Aggressive", 
"Conservative", "Visionary", "Arrogant", "Professional", "Responsive", 
"Confident", "Accessible", "Timely", "Focused", "Niche", "None"
), class = "factor"), Proportion = c(0.54, 0.48, 0.33, 0.35, 
0.47, 0.3, 0.43, 0.29, 0.36, 0.38, 0.45, 0.32, 0.27, 0.22, 0.26, 
0.95, 0.57, 0.42, 0.38, 0.5, 0.31, 0.31, 0.12, 0.88, 0.55, 0.55, 
0.31, 0.4, 0.5, 0.34, 0.53, 0.3, 0.41, 0.41, 0.46, 0.34, 0.22, 
0.17, 0.28, 0.94, 0.62, 0.46, 0.41, 0.53, 0.34, 0.36, 0.1, 0.84
), n = c(240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 
240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 
240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 258L, 258L, 258L, 258L, 258L, 258L, 258L, 
258L, 258L, 258L, 258L, 258L, 258L, 258L, 258L, 258L, 258L, 258L, 
258L, 258L, 258L, 258L, 258L, 258L)), .Names = c("Year", "Response", 
"Proportion", "n"), row.names = c(NA, -48L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Create a circular mapping on a scatterplot, using basics:

```
df$degree <- seq(0,345,15) # 24 responses, equals 15 degrees per response
df$o <- df$Proportion * sin(df$degree * pi / 180) # SOH
df$a <- df$Proportion * cos(df$degree * pi / 180) # CAH
df$o100 <- 1 * sin(df$degree * pi / 180) # Outer ring x
df$a100 <- 1 * cos(df$degree * pi / 180) # Outer ring y 
df$a75 <- 0.75 * cos(df$degree * pi / 180) # 75% ring y
df$o75 <- 0.75 * sin(df$degree * pi / 180) # 75% ring x
df$o50 <- 0.5 * sin(df$degree * pi / 180) # 50% ring x
df$a50 <- 0.5 * cos(df$degree * pi / 180) # 50% ring y
```

And plot. I cheated here to get them to connect in the last position by double plotting row 1 and 25 again:

```
p = plot_ly()

for(i in 1:24) {
  p <- add_trace(
    p, 
    x = c(d$o100[i],0), 
    y = c(d$a100[i],0), 
    evaluate = TRUE,
    line = list(color = "#d3d3d3", dash = "3px"),
    showlegend = FALSE
    )
}

p %>% 
  add_trace(data = d[c(1:48,1,25),], x = o, y = a, color = Year, 
            mode = "lines+markers",
            hoverinfo = "text", 
            text = paste(Year, Response,round(Proportion * 100), "%")) %>% 
  add_trace(data = d, x = o100, y = a100, 
            text = Response,
            hoverinfo = "none",
            textposition = "top middle", mode = "lines+text", 
            line = list(color = "#d3d3d3", dash = "3px", shape = "spline"),
            showlegend = FALSE) %>% 
  add_trace(data = d, x = o50, y = a50, mode = "lines", 
            line = list(color = "#d3d3d3", dash = "3px", shape = "spline"), 
            hoverinfo = "none",
            showlegend = FALSE) %>% 
  add_trace(data = d, x = o75, y = a75, mode = "lines", 
            line = list(color = "#d3d3d3", dash = "3px", shape = "spline"), 
            hoverinfo = "none",
            showlegend = FALSE) %>%
  layout(
    autosize = FALSE,
    hovermode = "closest",     
    autoscale = TRUE,
    width = 800,
    height = 800,
    xaxis = list(range = c(-1.25,1.25), showticklabels = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showgrid = FALSE),
    yaxis = list(range = c(-1.25,1.25), showticklabels = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showgrid = FALSE))
```

<s>As you can see, I've got it with the exception of <s>that last connecting line, and</s> the lines that pass from the origin to the text of the response.</s>

[image]

Comment: This is great! Do you have a link to the plotly graph?

Answer (score -3):

As far as I can see you have already obtained your plot with ggplot2 (example picture ). If this is true the easiest think you should do to add plotly functionalities to your plot is running `ggplotly()` on your ggplot object , like within the example below:

```
install.packages(c("ggplot2","plotly"))
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

plot <- ggplot(data =mtcars, aes(x =  mpg, y = cyl))+
 geom_point()

ggplotly (plot)
```

which will result into the following interactive plot:

[image]

Comment: it does not really answer the question.

Comment: Yeah I would argue is because we should better explicit are the question, as explained by @Uwe block

Comment: Yes this would be easy, except that updates to ggplot2 v2+ broke the code I was using to generate the plot. If you look at the updates I made to the question, you'll see the the code for the original plot is not so simple like it appears plotly may be.