# Change graph from static to interactive using ggplotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I tried to change my graph to interactive but i get error and searched for it but couldn't find the answer.

so Please Help .

Here's my full [data](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0By2lPFjKRVKWOWZOSDRSS1RLU0U)"All.smry"

here's the output from `dput` for 400 rows from "All" dataframe

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(1472994661, 1472994721, 1472994781, 
1472994840, 1472994901, 1472994961, 1472995025, 1472995082, 1472995142, 
1472995201, 1472995261, 1472995321, 1472995382, 1472995441, 1472995501, 
1472995561, 1472995620, 1472995682, 1472995741, 1472995801, 1472995861, 
1472995921, 1472995981, 1472996041, 1472996100, 1472996161, 1472996223, 
1472996280, 1472996340, 1472996400, 1472996463, 1472996520, 1472996581, 
1472996641, 1472996701, 1472996761, 1472996821, 1472996882, 1472996941, 
1472997001, 1472997061, 1472997121, 1472997181, 1472997241, 1472997301, 
1472997360, 1472997421, 1472997481, 1472997541, 1472997600, 1472997662, 
1472997722, 1472997783, 1472997841, 1472997903, 1472997961, 1472998020, 
1472998082, 1472998141, 1472998202, 1472998263, 1472998320, 1472998381, 
1472998442, 1472998501, 1472998561, 1472998621, 1472998681, 1472998740, 
1472998801, 1472998861, 1472998921, 1472998982, 1472999042, 1472999101, 
1472999161, 1472999221, 1472999280, 1472999341, 1472999401, 1472999463, 
1472999520, 1472999582, 1472999641, 1472999701, 1472999761, 1472999821, 
1472999882, 1472999941, 1473000002, 1473000063, 1473000120, 1473000181, 
1473000241, 1473000301, 1473000360, 1473000421, 1473000480, 1473000541, 
1473000604, 1473000661, 1473000721, 1473000783, 1473000842, 1473000901, 
1473000962, 1473001021, 1473001081, 1473001142, 1473001201, 1473001261, 
1473001321, 1473001382, 1473001442, 1473001502, 1473001561, 1473001621, 
1473001681, 1473001741, 1473001800, 1473001862, 1473001921, 1473001982, 
1473002042, 1473002101, 1473002161, 1473002221, 1473002282, 1473002341, 
1473002401, 1473002462, 1473002525, 1473002582, 1473002641, 1473002701, 
1473002762, 1473002822, 1473002883, 1473002942, 1473003002, 1473003062, 
1473003124, 1473003181, 1473003240, 1473003301, 1473003361, 1473003421, 
1473003484, 1473003542, 1473003601, 1473003662, 1473003721, 1473003785, 
1473003841, 1473003907, 1473003962, 1473004022, 1473004085, 1473004141, 
1473004201, 1473004261, 1473004321, 1473004381, 1473004441, 1473004501, 
1473004562, 1473004620, 1473004682, 1473004741, 1473004802, 1473004863, 
1473004923, 1473004980, 1473005045, 1473005103, 1473005162, 1473005222, 
1473005282, 1473005344, 1473005402, 1473005461, 1473005521, 1473005581, 
1473005646, 1473005703, 1473005761, 1473005821, 1473005883, 1473005943, 
1473006001, 1473006062, 1473006121, 1473006181, 1473006241, 1473006302, 
1473006361, 1473006421, 1473006481, 1473006542, 1473006602, 1473006661, 
1473006722, 1473006781, 1473006841, 1473006903, 1473006961, 1473007021, 
1473007081, 1473007142, 1473007201, 1473007263, 1473007321, 1473007381, 
1473007441, 1473007502, 1473007565, 1473007627, 1473007685, 1473007746, 
1473007803, 1473007863, 1473007922, 1473007982, 1473008042, 1473008106, 
1473008161, 1473008221, 1473008281, 1473008344, 1473008402, 1473008461, 
1473008521, 1473008582, 1473008655, 1473008704, 1473008761, 1473008821, 
1473008881, 1473008941, 1473009001, 1473009061, 1473009121, 1473009180, 
1473009241, 1473009301, 1473009362, 1473009422, 1473009481, 1473009542, 
1473009603, 1473009662, 1473009724, 1473009781, 1473009843, 1473009902, 
1473009962, 1473010021, 1473010081, 1473010141, 1473010202, 1473010261, 
1473010322, 1473010381, 1473010441, 1473010503, 1473010562, 1473010623, 
1473010682, 1473010744, 1473010803, 1473010862, 1473010922, 1473010982, 
1473011042, 1473011102, 1473011162, 1473011221, 1473011282, 1473011342, 
1473011401, 1473011461, 1473011523, 1473011581, 1473011641, 1473011702, 
1473011761, 1473011821, 1473011881, 1473011941, 1473012002, 1473012061, 
1473012122, 1473012186, 1473012263, 1473012316, 1473012373, 1473012435, 
1473012499, 1473012541, 1473012603, 1473012661, 1473012720, 1473012781, 
1473012841, 1473012900, 1473012961, 1473013021, 1473013082, 1473013141, 
1473013201, 1473013263, 1473013321, 1473013381, 1473013441, 1473013501, 
1473013561, 1473013622, 1473013681, 1473013741, 1473013801, 1473013861, 
1473013923, 1473013981, 1473014041, 1473014101, 1473014160, 1473014222, 
1473014282, 1473014341, 1473014401, 1473014462, 1473014523, 1473014581, 
1473014640, 1473014701, 1473014762, 1473014821, 1473014881, 1473014940, 
1473015001, 1473015063, 1473015121, 1473015181, 1473015241, 1473015305, 
1473015360, 1473015421, 1473015481, 1473015541, 1473015602, 1473015661, 
1473015721, 1473015781, 1473015842, 1473015901, 1473015961, 1473016021, 
1473016081, 1473016141, 1473016201, 1473016262, 1473016321, 1473016382, 
1473016442, 1473016503, 1473016562, 1473016621, 1473016683, 1473016746, 
1473016805, 1473016863, 1473016922, 1473016981, 1473017041, 1473017101, 
1473017161, 1473017222, 1473017281, 1473017341, 1473017401, 1473017461, 
1473017521, 1473017581, 1473017641, 1473017701, 1473017761, 1473017820, 
1473017881, 1473017941, 1473018001, 1473018061, 1473018122, 1473018181, 
1473018241, 1473018302, 1473018363, 1473018423, 1473018492, 1473018543, 
1473018602), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "GMT"), 
    Distance = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L), .Label = "4.201", class = "factor"), TravelTime = c(4.18333333333333, 
    4.03333333333333, 4.03333333333333, 4.03333333333333, 4.11666666666667, 
    3.98333333333333, 3.98333333333333, 3.93333333333333, 3.98333333333333, 
    3.98333333333333, 3.98333333333333, 3.93333333333333, 4.1, 
    3.8, 3.75, 4.1, 4.1, 4.25, 4.1, 3.96666666666667, 4.1, 4.3, 
    4.16666666666667, 3.96666666666667, 3.98333333333333, 3.98333333333333, 
    4, 3.85, 3.88333333333333, 3.85, 3.96666666666667, 4, 3.96666666666667, 
    4.5, 4.46666666666667, 3.93333333333333, 4.13333333333333, 
    4.38333333333333, 4.2, 4.18333333333333, 4.25, 4.25, 4.2, 
    4, 4.15, 4.3, 4.31666666666667, 4.4, 4.48333333333333, 4.03333333333333, 
    4.03333333333333, 4.2, 4.11666666666667, 4.1, 4.06666666666667, 
    4.06666666666667, 4.05, 4.05, 4.61666666666667, 4.45, 4.35, 
    4.16666666666667, 4.2, 4.11666666666667, 4.18333333333333, 
    4.23333333333333, 4.53333333333333, 4.15, 4.63333333333333, 
    4.76666666666667, 5.01666666666667, 4.78333333333333, 4.83333333333333, 
    4.8, 4.93333333333333, 5.1, 5.03333333333333, 5.06666666666667, 
    5.43333333333333, 5.11666666666667, 4.9, 4.81666666666667, 
    4.78333333333333, 4.96666666666667, 4.81666666666667, 4.68333333333333, 
    4.73333333333333, 4.61666666666667, 4.56666666666667, 4.58333333333333, 
    4.5, 4.43333333333333, 4.73333333333333, 4.7, 4.71666666666667, 
    4.75, 4.9, 4.86666666666667, 4.63333333333333, 4.38333333333333, 
    4.61666666666667, 4.43333333333333, 4.2, 4.16666666666667, 
    4.31666666666667, 4.25, 4.3, 4.25, 4.21666666666667, 3.93333333333333, 
    4.16666666666667, 4.16666666666667, 4.21666666666667, 4.21666666666667, 
    4.2, 4.16666666666667, 4.51666666666667, 4.5, 4.56666666666667, 
    4.36666666666667, 4.51666666666667, 4.5, 4.68333333333333, 
    4.58333333333333, 4.31666666666667, 4.41666666666667, 4.55, 
    4.9, 4.86666666666667, 4.48333333333333, 4.48333333333333, 
    4.46666666666667, 4.4, 4.58333333333333, 4.4, 4.4, 4.73333333333333, 
    4.78333333333333, 5.15, 5.01666666666667, 5.33333333333333, 
    5.46666666666667, 5.18333333333333, 5.01666666666667, 4.88333333333333, 
    4.83333333333333, 4.86666666666667, 4.83333333333333, 4.8, 
    4.8, 4.83333333333333, 4.25, 4.16666666666667, 4.88333333333333, 
    4.73333333333333, 4.85, 5.06666666666667, 5.25, 5.08333333333333, 
    5.38333333333333, 5.18333333333333, 5.41666666666667, 5.56666666666667, 
    5.81666666666667, 5.15, 4.81666666666667, 4.73333333333333, 
    4.91666666666667, 4.58333333333333, 4.65, 5.2, 5.13333333333333, 
    5.05, 4.58333333333333, 4.91666666666667, 4.6, 4.6, 4.93333333333333, 
    4.95, 4.91666666666667, 4.93333333333333, 5.18333333333333, 
    5.35, 4.75, 4.73333333333333, 4.53333333333333, 4.38333333333333, 
    4.48333333333333, 4.48333333333333, 4.4, 4.25, 4.56666666666667, 
    4.4, 4.26666666666667, 4.25, 3.73333333333333, 3.66666666666667, 
    3.81666666666667, 3.81666666666667, 3.91666666666667, 3.85, 
    3.81666666666667, 4.08333333333333, 3.91666666666667, 4.05, 
    4.05, 3.98333333333333, 4.23333333333333, 4.21666666666667, 
    4.13333333333333, 4.15, 4.38333333333333, 4.41666666666667, 
    4.43333333333333, 4.53333333333333, 4.56666666666667, 4.73333333333333, 
    4.8, 5.03333333333333, 4.96666666666667, 4.6, 4.46666666666667, 
    4.5, 5.5, 5.31666666666667, 4.61666666666667, 4.66666666666667, 
    4.65, 4.85, 4.85, 4.86666666666667, 5.83333333333333, 6.75, 
    6.93333333333333, 8.18333333333333, 7.81666666666667, 7.03333333333333, 
    5.4, 5.58333333333333, 5.81666666666667, 5.93333333333333, 
    5.86666666666667, 5.23333333333333, 4.78333333333333, 4.81666666666667, 
    4.75, 4.81666666666667, 6.66666666666667, 6.88333333333333, 
    7.3, 6.75, 6.51666666666667, 6.18333333333333, 5.95, 4.78333333333333, 
    4.6, 7.7, 8.01666666666667, 5.51666666666667, 5.65, 5.98333333333333, 
    5.9, 5.86666666666667, 4.71666666666667, 4.71666666666667, 
    4.98333333333333, 4.91666666666667, 5.01666666666667, 4.55, 
    4.9, 5.26666666666667, 6.6, 8, 8.4, 5.51666666666667, 5.45, 
    5.78333333333333, 5.9, 5.71666666666667, 6.36666666666667, 
    6.31666666666667, 6.31666666666667, 6.31666666666667, 6.08333333333333, 
    5.66666666666667, 6.1, 5.75, 5.28333333333333, 6.06666666666667, 
    5.98333333333333, 6.58333333333333, 6.56666666666667, 7.2, 
    6.65, 7.55, 7.16666666666667, 7, 6.3, 6.85, 4.56666666666667, 
    5.33333333333333, 5.33333333333333, 5.05, 4.85, 5.81666666666667, 
    6.9, 6.9, 6.58333333333333, 7.18333333333333, 7.15, 7.15, 
    7.53333333333333, 7.45, 4.21666666666667, 4.13333333333333, 
    4.2, 4.25, 4.25, 3.86666666666667, 4.2, 5.71666666666667, 
    6.25, 5.58333333333333, 6.33333333333333, 4.56666666666667, 
    4.7, 4.75, 5.83333333333333, 6.68333333333333, 6.38333333333333, 
    6.15, 6.65, 6.78333333333333, 6.86666666666667, 6.26666666666667, 
    6.11666666666667, 6.13333333333333, 5.98333333333333, 5.53333333333333, 
    5.56666666666667, 7.4, 7.1, 7.03333333333333, 7.16666666666667, 
    6.68333333333333, 6.43333333333333, 6.46666666666667, 6.05, 
    6.6, 8.61666666666667, 8, 9.61666666666667, 6.43333333333333, 
    5.25, 5.63333333333333, 4.6, 4.58333333333333, 5.36666666666667, 
    8.03333333333333, 5.61666666666667, 5.9, 6.05, 6.25, 6.13333333333333, 
    6.71666666666667, 6.23333333333333, 6.58333333333333, 6.88333333333333, 
    6.66666666666667, 6.43333333333333, 7.2, 5.41666666666667, 
    5.56666666666667, 5.3, 4.8, 8.13333333333333, 5.01666666666667, 
    4.7, 5.01666666666667, 4.95, 5.55, 5, 4.36666666666667, 5.11666666666667, 
    5.11666666666667, 5.18333333333333, 5.28333333333333, 5.2, 
    5.23333333333333, 5.03333333333333, 5.13333333333333, 5.3, 
    5.23333333333333, 4.95, 4.9, 4.78333333333333, 4.83333333333333, 
    5.03333333333333, 5.21666666666667, 5.06666666666667), hour = c(13.1836111111111, 
    13.2002777777778, 13.2169444444444, 13.2333333333333, 13.2502777777778, 
    13.2669444444444, 13.2847222222222, 13.3005555555556, 13.3172222222222, 
    13.3336111111111, 13.3502777777778, 13.3669444444444, 13.3838888888889, 
    13.4002777777778, 13.4169444444444, 13.4336111111111, 13.45, 
    13.4672222222222, 13.4836111111111, 13.5002777777778, 13.5169444444444, 
    13.5336111111111, 13.5502777777778, 13.5669444444444, 13.5833333333333, 
    13.6002777777778, 13.6175, 13.6333333333333, 13.65, 13.6666666666667, 
    13.6841666666667, 13.7, 13.7169444444444, 13.7336111111111, 
    13.7502777777778, 13.7669444444444, 13.7836111111111, 13.8005555555556, 
    13.8169444444444, 13.8336111111111, 13.8502777777778, 13.8669444444444, 
    13.8836111111111, 13.9002777777778, 13.9169444444444, 13.9333333333333, 
    13.9502777777778, 13.9669444444444, 13.9836111111111, 14, 
    14.0172222222222, 14.0338888888889, 14.0508333333333, 14.0669444444444, 
    14.0841666666667, 14.1002777777778, 14.1166666666667, 14.1338888888889, 
    14.1502777777778, 14.1672222222222, 14.1841666666667, 14.2, 
    14.2169444444444, 14.2338888888889, 14.2502777777778, 14.2669444444444, 
    14.2836111111111, 14.3002777777778, 14.3166666666667, 14.3336111111111, 
    14.3502777777778, 14.3669444444444, 14.3838888888889, 14.4005555555556, 
    14.4169444444444, 14.4336111111111, 14.4502777777778, 14.4666666666667, 
    14.4836111111111, 14.5002777777778, 14.5175, 14.5333333333333, 
    14.5505555555556, 14.5669444444444, 14.5836111111111, 14.6002777777778, 
    14.6169444444444, 14.6338888888889, 14.6502777777778, 14.6672222222222, 
    14.6841666666667, 14.7, 14.7169444444444, 14.7336111111111, 
    14.7502777777778, 14.7666666666667, 14.7836111111111, 14.8, 
    14.8169444444444, 14.8344444444444, 14.8502777777778, 14.8669444444444, 
    14.8841666666667, 14.9005555555556, 14.9169444444444, 14.9338888888889, 
    14.9502777777778, 14.9669444444444, 14.9838888888889, 15.0002777777778, 
    15.0169444444444, 15.0336111111111, 15.0505555555556, 15.0672222222222, 
    15.0838888888889, 15.1002777777778, 15.1169444444444, 15.1336111111111, 
    15.1502777777778, 15.1666666666667, 15.1838888888889, 15.2002777777778, 
    15.2172222222222, 15.2338888888889, 15.2502777777778, 15.2669444444444, 
    15.2836111111111, 15.3005555555556, 15.3169444444444, 15.3336111111111, 
    15.3505555555556, 15.3680555555556, 15.3838888888889, 15.4002777777778, 
    15.4169444444444, 15.4338888888889, 15.4505555555556, 15.4675, 
    15.4838888888889, 15.5005555555556, 15.5172222222222, 15.5344444444444, 
    15.5502777777778, 15.5666666666667, 15.5836111111111, 15.6002777777778, 
    15.6169444444444, 15.6344444444444, 15.6505555555556, 15.6669444444444, 
    15.6838888888889, 15.7002777777778, 15.7180555555556, 15.7336111111111, 
    15.7519444444444, 15.7672222222222, 15.7838888888889, 15.8013888888889, 
    15.8169444444444, 15.8336111111111, 15.8502777777778, 15.8669444444444, 
    15.8836111111111, 15.9002777777778, 15.9169444444444, 15.9338888888889, 
    15.95, 15.9672222222222, 15.9836111111111, 16.0005555555556, 
    16.0175, 16.0341666666667, 16.05, 16.0680555555556, 16.0841666666667, 
    16.1005555555556, 16.1172222222222, 16.1338888888889, 16.1511111111111, 
    16.1672222222222, 16.1836111111111, 16.2002777777778, 16.2169444444444, 
    16.235, 16.2508333333333, 16.2669444444444, 16.2836111111111, 
    16.3008333333333, 16.3175, 16.3336111111111, 16.3505555555556, 
    16.3669444444444, 16.3836111111111, 16.4002777777778, 16.4172222222222, 
    16.4336111111111, 16.4502777777778, 16.4669444444444, 16.4838888888889, 
    16.5005555555556, 16.5169444444444, 16.5338888888889, 16.5502777777778, 
    16.5669444444444, 16.5841666666667, 16.6002777777778, 16.6169444444444, 
    16.6336111111111, 16.6505555555556, 16.6669444444444, 16.6841666666667, 
    16.7002777777778, 16.7169444444444, 16.7336111111111, 16.7505555555556, 
    16.7680555555556, 16.7852777777778, 16.8013888888889, 16.8183333333333, 
    16.8341666666667, 16.8508333333333, 16.8672222222222, 16.8838888888889, 
    16.9005555555556, 16.9183333333333, 16.9336111111111, 16.9502777777778, 
    16.9669444444444, 16.9844444444444, 17.0005555555556, 17.0169444444444, 
    17.0336111111111, 17.0505555555556, 17.0708333333333, 17.0844444444444, 
    17.1002777777778, 17.1169444444444, 17.1336111111111, 17.1502777777778, 
    17.1669444444444, 17.1836111111111, 17.2002777777778, 17.2166666666667, 
    17.2336111111111, 17.2502777777778, 17.2672222222222, 17.2838888888889, 
    17.3002777777778, 17.3172222222222, 17.3341666666667, 17.3505555555556, 
    17.3677777777778, 17.3836111111111, 17.4008333333333, 17.4172222222222, 
    17.4338888888889, 17.4502777777778, 17.4669444444444, 17.4836111111111, 
    17.5005555555556, 17.5169444444444, 17.5338888888889, 17.5502777777778, 
    17.5669444444444, 17.5841666666667, 17.6005555555556, 17.6175, 
    17.6338888888889, 17.6511111111111, 17.6675, 17.6838888888889, 
    17.7005555555556, 17.7172222222222, 17.7338888888889, 17.7505555555556, 
    17.7672222222222, 17.7836111111111, 17.8005555555556, 17.8172222222222, 
    17.8336111111111, 17.8502777777778, 17.8675, 17.8836111111111, 
    17.9002777777778, 17.9172222222222, 17.9336111111111, 17.9502777777778, 
    17.9669444444444, 17.9836111111111, 18.0005555555556, 18.0169444444444, 
    18.0338888888889, 18.0516666666667, 18.0730555555556, 18.0877777777778, 
    18.1036111111111, 18.1208333333333, 18.1386111111111, 18.1502777777778, 
    18.1675, 18.1836111111111, 18.2, 18.2169444444444, 18.2336111111111, 
    18.25, 18.2669444444444, 18.2836111111111, 18.3005555555556, 
    18.3169444444444, 18.3336111111111, 18.3508333333333, 18.3669444444444, 
    18.3836111111111, 18.4002777777778, 18.4169444444444, 18.4336111111111, 
    18.4505555555556, 18.4669444444444, 18.4836111111111, 18.5002777777778, 
    18.5169444444444, 18.5341666666667, 18.5502777777778, 18.5669444444444, 
    18.5836111111111, 18.6, 18.6172222222222, 18.6338888888889, 
    18.6502777777778, 18.6669444444444, 18.6838888888889, 18.7008333333333, 
    18.7169444444444, 18.7333333333333, 18.7502777777778, 18.7672222222222, 
    18.7836111111111, 18.8002777777778, 18.8166666666667, 18.8336111111111, 
    18.8508333333333, 18.8669444444444, 18.8836111111111, 18.9002777777778, 
    18.9180555555556, 18.9333333333333, 18.9502777777778, 18.9669444444444, 
    18.9836111111111, 19.0005555555556, 19.0169444444444, 19.0336111111111, 
    19.0502777777778, 19.0672222222222, 19.0836111111111, 19.1002777777778, 
    19.1169444444444, 19.1336111111111, 19.1502777777778, 19.1669444444444, 
    19.1838888888889, 19.2002777777778, 19.2172222222222, 19.2338888888889, 
    19.2508333333333, 19.2672222222222, 19.2836111111111, 19.3008333333333, 
    19.3183333333333, 19.3347222222222, 19.3508333333333, 19.3672222222222, 
    19.3836111111111, 19.4002777777778, 19.4169444444444, 19.4336111111111, 
    19.4505555555556, 19.4669444444444, 19.4836111111111, 19.5002777777778, 
    19.5169444444444, 19.5336111111111, 19.5502777777778, 19.5669444444444, 
    19.5836111111111, 19.6002777777778, 19.6166666666667, 19.6336111111111, 
    19.6502777777778, 19.6669444444444, 19.6836111111111, 19.7005555555556, 
    19.7169444444444, 19.7336111111111, 19.7505555555556, 19.7675, 
    19.7841666666667, 19.8033333333333, 19.8175, 19.8338888888889
    ), day = structure(c(17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 
    17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 
    17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 
    17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 
    17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 
    17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 
    17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 
    17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 
    17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 
    17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 
    17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 
    17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 
    17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 
    17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 
    17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 
    17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 
    17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 
    17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 
    17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 
    17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 
    17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 
    17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 
    17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 
    17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 
    17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 
    17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 
    17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 
    17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 
    17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 
    17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 
    17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 
    17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 
    17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 
    17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 
    17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 
    17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 
    17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 
    17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 
    17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 
    17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 
    17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 
    17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 
    17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 
    17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 
    17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048, 17048), class = "Date")), .Names = c("Date", 
"Distance", "TravelTime", "hour", "day"), row.names = c(NA, 400L
), class = "data.frame")
```

then please use this code

```
All.smry = All %>% 
        mutate(hour.group = cut(hour, breaks=seq(0,24,0.25), labels=seq(0,23.75,0.25), include.lowest=TRUE),
               hour.group = as.numeric(as.character(hour.group))) %>%
        group_by(day, hour.group) %>%
        summarise(meanTT = mean(TravelTime)) %>%
        mutate(spiralTime = as.POSIXct(day) + hour.group*3600-7200)
```

here's my code for graph

```
`        R1 <-ggplot(All.smry) +
                geom_segment(size=1.1, aes(x=as.numeric(hour.group), xend=as.numeric(hour.group) + 0.25, 
                                           y=spiralTime, yend=spiralTime, colour=meanTT)) +
            scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0,24), breaks=0:23, minor_breaks=0:24,
                               labels=paste0(rep(c(12,1:11),2), rep(c("AM","PM"),each=12))) +
            scale_y_datetime(limits=range(All.smry$spiralTime) + c(-3*24*3600,0), 
                             breaks=seq(min(All.smry$spiralTime), max(All.smry$spiralTime),"1 day"),
                             date_labels="%b %e") +
            scale_colour_gradientn(colours=c("#009966","orange","#FF0000","#660000")) +
            coord_polar() +
            theme_bw(base_size=10) + 
            labs(x="Hour",y="Day",color="Mean Travel Time") +
            theme(panel.grid.minor.x=element_line(colour="grey60", size=0.3))+
            theme(axis.title.y=element_blank(),axis.text.y=element_blank(),axis.ticks.y=element_blank()
                  ,axis.title.x=element_blank())+
              theme(text = element_text(size=7))+
            theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

`
The function i use to get interactive 
    ggplotly(R1)

here's the error

```
Error in zero_range(to) : x must be length 1 or 2
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In if (nchar(plot$labels$title %||% "") > 0) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In min(z$x.range) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
3: In max(z$x.range) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
4: In min(z$y.range) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
5: In max(z$y.range) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

Any help please ? .

Comment: I would be best to reduce the data to a substantially smaller subset that reproduces the error and that can be pasted here rather than a 14k long csv.

Comment: i tried to use only 100 rows , and still get the same error, how many rows of the data u would like and think it'll be enough ?

Comment: i edited the question , please have a look again

Comment: I get an error trying to load the data, does it work for you on a clean session?

Comment: me too , please give me a moment to solve it , i just wrote my dataframe's name into dput and copied it here .

Comment: I'm sorry , i'm trying to solve it , but don't know why this error happenes , i get th out put and don't change anything and errors happens , that's strange . do you have any idea why ?

Comment: I don't know, dput() is usually the way to go to share data.

Comment: I edited it , i got another solution , please follow what i wrote .

Comment: The problem comes from coord_polar, there are several post on the subjects, your best chance could be [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37670412/can-i-recreate-this-polar-coordinate-graphic-in-plotly)

Comment: Thanks alot, it's gonna take a long time to change my graph to plotly, anyway, i appreciate ur help :D .